# Find particular string inside URL with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I need to "regex" – in JavaScript – a string like:

```
http://some.domain.com/v/v1.0-4/19232_102032_21111986_n.jpg?param=fejrlwfje&list=fklwefljfre
```

I need to extract `19232_102032_21111986_n`, that is, just the name of the image between `http://some.domain.com/v/v1.0-4/` and `.jpg?param=fejrlwfje&list=fklwefljfre`, and assign it to a variable.

Comment: If you know before and after part of your match then it may not require any regex

Comment: Split with `?`, then the first part with `/` and get the last item and strip it from `.jpg` ... Or, yes, use a regex.

Comment: No solution works for you, do they? Try `'http://some.domain.com/v/v1.0-4/19232_102032_21111986_n.jpg?param=fejrlwfje&list=fklwefljfre'.match(/\/([^\/?]+)\.jpg(?:\?|$)/)[1]`

Comment: Thanks but I asking specifically for a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is the finest solution, thanks. If you write the answer, you deserve upvote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\/([^\/?]+)\.jpg(?:\?|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV8cO9/1)

**Pattern description**:

- `\/` - a slash
- `([^\/?]+)` - Group 1 (the file name) matching 1 or more characters other than `/` and `?`
- `\.jpg` -  a literal `.jpg`
- `(?:\?|$)` - a non-capturing group matching either `?` or the end of string.

```js
var s = 'http://some.domain.com/v/v1.0-4/19232_102032_21111986_n.jpg?param=fejrlwfje&li‌st=fklwefljfre';
var m  = s.match(/\/([^\/?]+)\.jpg(?:\?|$)/);
document.body.innerHTML = m ? m[1] : "No match!";
```

Comment: Absolutely the finest solution, great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = "http://some.domain.com/v/v1.0-4/19232_102032_21111986_n.jpg?param=fejrlwfje&list=fklwefljfre"
var result = /\/([a-z_0-9]+)\.jpg/.exec(s)[1];
```

Comment: This will fail on url using non-ascii characters

Comment: @Richard I know. But it answers the question and will never match anything unexpected )

Comment: Good, but [still not perfect](https://regex101.com/r/qW4xB2/2). Without more context details, your regex is correct and is likely to work in the majority of cases, but it is still not 100% safe. The point is to match this at the end  of the string or right before a `?` (query string). Oh, see Richard's answer - that is "more correct".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew maybe you're right. Hard to tell what OP should expect in your example. Anyway - regexp's are bad here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no '?' in the string you want to match, you can try :

```
/\/([^?/]*)(\?|$)/.exec("http://some.domain.com/v/v1.0-4/19232_102032_21111986_n.jpg?param=fejrlwfje&list=fklwefljfre")[1].slice(0,-4)
```

This will match all characters after the last '/', that are not '/' or '?' and before '?' or the end of the string.

The slice call is used to removed the '.jpg' part.

Comment: You should escape the `/` in the pattern. Also, `.slice(0,-4)` might not be the best way to get rid of the extension that may go missing. Just match the extension.

Comment: I doesn't need to be escaped since it is bewteen `[` `]`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, it can be achieved without regex by using `String.split`, `String.substr` and `Array.lastIndexOf` functions:

```
var url = "http://some.domain.com/v/v1.0-4/19232_102032_21111986_n.jpg?param=fejrlwfje&list=fklwefljfre",
    url_part = url.split("?")[0],
    img_file = url_part.substr(url_part.lastIndexOf("/")+1).split(".")[0];

console.log(img_file);   // "19232_102032_21111986_n"
```